# VirtualBox VM is not accessible after the host crash

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm running RHEL8 on my hardware and I need to use VM with VirtualBox to test my code.

For some reason my host machine just crashed.

When I started it back and re-run the VirtualBox, I see that the machine status is "Aborted". I tried to play it, it ran, asked me for a user name and password and then after I provided it said "Last successful login was..." and then came back to the user name request.

I run the same RHEL8 in the guest...

Is it possible to recover it?

Comment: Does the VM have any backups or snapshots to roll back to before this happened?

Comment: If the VM was running at the time of the host crash, your description suggests the VM suffered som serious damage. Can you manage to start it in terminal mode before the main start. That may offer a recovery sequence

Comment: @harrymc, no it doesn't.

Comment: @John, yes, it was running. And for the Terminal mode - how do I do it?

Comment: Please see if this offers any help:    https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/installation_guide/ap-rescuemode

Comment: If nothing helps, you might need to recreate the VM.